# Page not found java project deployed using tomcat

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat9, openjdk-12

I've got one java web based project. Build using JDK 1.8 and Using Intellij as IDE.
Using tomcat to deploy the product

Essentially in our product I was trying to test a few things with a class.
Very recently what has happened is whenever I am compiling and putting it inside our project it is saying page not found.

So, I reverted my code base to Out of the box state, compiled and put it back. Still it
s giving me page not found error.

One annoying this about this error is, In the logs I don't have a single error.
So it's not even hinting on where to look or what's going on.

Second annoying this was, like I did some series of changes , but for every change I took a back up. Think of it like, if default OTB was Revision 1, My changes are in Revision 2,3,4. From revision 4 I started to get this error. But when I take revision 1 and put it back. Still getting page not found. But if I take Revision 2 or 3. It is working.

I've compared all revisions and code wise there's no such change, which could break anything. I've a strong doubt that it could be one of the project structure settings.
I checked local history, but apparently local history refreshes every time you rebuild a project so no luck there.

I want to understand and resolve this problem.

Any tips on how to handle this, will help greatly.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some details, e.g. the version of Tomcat used and some logs? Seems like the deployment of your application failed (the errors are in the `localhost.<date>.log`).

Comment: That's what I meant. In my logs there's no error. The last line of my log says
Build successful.  Regarding the versions I've used. I've already tagged my env version details, like tomcat9, jdk8 and all.  In my local host there were some warnings but no errors. Anyhow, thanks for your time mate. I got the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer to this problem was Embarrassingly simple.

Our project was last certified with OpenJDK11 but I mixed two of my tasks and started using openJDK12.

I don't understand what exactly in OpenJDK12 broke this.
And I want to inspect what went wrong.

But for the current task at hand. 1 solution is as simple as reverting back to OpenJDK11. After that when I used this modified class it was working perfectly.

PS: Still not 100% sure if it was due to jdk version. But If it was I wonder why in logs it was not mentioning that error. Which says compiled using higher version of Java.

Comment: There are many log files (in Tomcat's `logs` directory), did you check them all or just the ones that appear on the console?

Comment: Nope. Checked all of these ..our Custom Documentum logs, Common-daemon-logs, catalina logs, host manager logs and localhost logs. Nothing Anywhere.